# How to set CheckBox margin dynamically in Silverlight

Tags: c#, silverlight, margin

I am creating `CheckBoxes` dynamically on my `grid`. Now I also want to set the `margin`(respected to the `CheckBox`) dynamically but not sure what would be the best way.

For example,

- If there is only **one** `CheckBox` then the `margin` should be `{5,0,0,0}`
- If there are **two** `CheckBoxes` then the first should have `{5,0,0,0}` and second should have `{10,0,0,0}` and so on. 
  I am concern with left margin. These check box creation is based on `List<String>`.

XAML:

```
<Grid x:Name="SynonymsGrid" Grid.Column="2" Margin="0,35,0,0" >
    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
    </Grid.RowDefinitions>
</Grid>
```

CODE-BEHIND:

```
List<String> names = new List<string>() { "one", "two", "three" };
foreach (var name in names)
    {
        CheckBox chb = new CheckBox();
        chb.Content = name;
        chb.Margin = new System.Windows.Thickness { Left = 5, Top = 0, Right = 0, Bottom = 0 };
        synonymsGrid.Children.Add(chb);
    }
```

Above code will set all check boxes at one location which is obvious. I thought of using `for loop` but not sure what is the best approach.

Solution :

```
for (int i = 0; i < names.Count; i++)
    {
        CheckBox chb = new CheckBox();
        chb.Content = names[i];
        chb.Margin = new System.Windows.Thickness { Left = i * 150, Top = 0, Right = 0, Bottom = 0 };
        synonymsGrid.Children.Add(chb);
    }
```

Comment: I've found a solution and updated the answer as well. Thanks for looking.

Comment: @OmegaMan Thanks for edit. I'll keep these things in mind for next time.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Why do all this visual GUI operations in the code behind when there are Xaml constructs/controls that do the same thing?

---

To do this dynamically in Xaml...here are the steps.

First off, the `StackPanel` can evenly space out the checkboxes in a horizontal fashion instead of using a grid then margin'ing the controls to the right location. *Note, you could even stop right here and replace your grid with a `StackPanel` and not even have a need for this question*

But what makes it data driven (dynamic) in the Xaml paradigm, one uses the `ItemsControl` which specifies a *panel* or an area which will be our horizontal space (`StackPanel`) that will hold the dynamic items. Each of those dynamic items will be derived from a template containing a checkbox.

For example to achieve the three checkboxes based off of your `Names` list uses this :

[image]

Simply bind your list of names to `ItemsControl` which uses the `StackPanel` and a `CheckBox` using this Xaml:

```
<ItemsControl  ItemsSource="{Binding Names}">
    <ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
        <ItemsPanelTemplate>
            <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal" />
        </ItemsPanelTemplate>
    </ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
    <ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <CheckBox Content="{Binding}"
                        Margin="5,0,0,0" />
        </DataTemplate>
    </ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
</ItemsControl>
```